# Adding Maximise window button to Team Foundation Server 2013 templates

Tags: tfs

We have recently migrated from Team Foundation Server 2010 to Team Foundation Server 2013 Update 2. In TFS 2013 template design for creating new bug/task etc. we found that there is no maximise window button available. Pls find below Image link . Kindly help me if there is any way to add maximise button next to close button.. If so how do I proceed with it. Kindly help me
http://postimg.org/image/94vh3kl2t/

Comment: you need to mention what have you tried so far before posting on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install TFS 2013 update 4 to get built in maximize buttons on all rich text boxes.

There is no way to add a maximize button next to the close button.

Comment: we will not be able to edit the inbuilt TFS scripts to get this change ?

Comment: No. Doing so would invalidate your warranty. It may also break servicing.

Comment: Hello, I'm using version 12.0.31101.0 which seems to correspond mentioned Update 4 and yet I cannot see anything but the close button.